# Upgrading Blackberry Dynamics app - native Linking error

Tags: ios, xamarin, blackberry, simulator, blackberry-dynamics

I am upgrading an existing app written using the Xamarin Bindings for Blackberry Dynamics on iOS. I have updated to the static SDK for iOS v8.1.0.37, and am using Visual Studio for Mac 8.7.8 on macOS Catalina 10.15.7. Xcode 12.0.1 and Xamarin.iOS 14.0.0.0.

After updating the SDK and replacing my references to GoodDynamics.iOS.dll and GoodDynamics.iOS.Launcher.dll (from the ios bindings for xamarin v 7.0.0.13), I tried to build and received the following error:

```
/Users/jweberfl/TFS/WinWeb/mobile/PartnerPodcasts/error MT5209: Error: in /Users/jweberfl/TFS/WinWeb/mobile/PartnerPodcasts/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/GD.framework/GD(nondga_model.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for free standing, file '/Users/jweberfl/TFS/WinWeb/mobile/PartnerPodcasts/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/GD.framework/GD' for architecture x86_64 (PartnerPodcasts) Native linking
```

I've done some searching for this error, but from what I can tell the solution seems to be to exclude certain architectures in the xcode build settings, which I don't see a way to replicate in Visual Studio for Mac. For reference, I am able to build and run the GreetingsClient sample in the 7.0.0.13 Examples folder. I also copied the mtouch arguments from that project into my existing project, so I have the updated arguments in place to link the SafariServices framework.

I'm a bit stuck here - can anyone provide any information on what setting/file/configuration might be causing this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

BB Dynamics does not support XCode 12 yet. Can you try using XCode 11?

Comment: Hello @GGhangura - thanks for your suggestion. While XCode 12 may not be officially supported, I can build and run the example projects with it installed. I spent the day converting one of those projects to house my code and was able to get a build working, so unfortunately I do not have the lattitude to test your suggestion. Even though I have solved the problem this way, I'm still curious as to why the upgrade path failed. As far as I can tell, the two projects are identical. In any case, I do appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Hi there are new BB certification files you have to add along with the usual GD.Framework files. These are documented on Blackberry website. They need to also be signed and embedded.

New Xcode build system

```
GD.framework
BlackBerryCerticom.xcframework
BlackBerryCerticomSBGSE.xcframework
```

Legacy Xcode build system

```
GD.framework
BlackBerryCerticom.framework
BlackBerryCerticomSBGSE.framework
```

https://docs.blackberry.com/en/development-tools/blackberry-dynamics-sdk-ios/8_1/blackberry-dynamics-sdk-ios-devguide/Steps-to-get-started-And-iOS/rqx1490022241984/Prepare-an-app-to-use-the-static-framework